# Execute remote commands for multiple workstations?

Tags: remote

I need to run same commands for 15 workstations.
E.g.

```
apt-get update
apt-get install gimp
cd && wget http://example.com/examplefile.mp4
```

I cannot use SSH because not the all workstations are running at the same time. Command should be queued and executed when workstations are booted.

Comment: explain: if not with ssh how are you suppose to connect to a system and execute this -remotely-?

Comment: When you turn on your workstations it could connect to master node and check what commands are queued for execution.